# Change dimensions of dynamically added ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox, height, width

I created a form in VBA where I dynamically add ListBoxes.

How do I change the width and height of the ListBox? All other things are being changed.

```vb
    Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
    Set lb = Me.controls.add("Forms.Listbox.1")
    With lb
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .Left = 180
        .Top = 16
        .MultiSelect = 1
        .Height = 270
        .Width = 665
    End with
```

I noticed Height and Width aren't in the property list of the ListBox. Could it be that I use the wrong ListBox type?

When I go through the code line by line, the ListBox size is as I want it.

Comment: The code looks good. I've created a form that takes height and width from a couple of combo boxes and sends these dimensions to an edited copy of your code. Have you tried adding Me.Repaint after an update?

Comment: Me.Repaint didn't work, however going trough the code line by line seems to work.

Comment: Is there anything else that happens after the ListBox creation?

Comment: I found the solution: After the creation, Items are added to the listboxes and I have set the heigth and width again after adding the item. This seems to work, but I still don't understand why it worked when going through the code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be

Me.Controls("Forms.Listbox.1").IntegralHeight = False
or
lb.IntegralHeight = False

Answer (score 0):

In my Word VBA script I dynamically added a ListBox item today and encountered the same error. The .Height and .Width property seem to be missing and the ListBox doesn't get resized when setting a custom height or width.
After a lot of troubleshooting I found out that the `MultiSelect` property is blocking the resizing if it is set to `fmMultiSelectMulti` or `fmMultiSelectExtended`.

So, I case anyone else runs into the problem:

FIRST set the width and the height and THEN AFTERWARDS set the `MultiSelect` property.

Couldn't believe that something like this is the problem...